# can't set both name and object arguments of addObserver method

Tags: macos, nsnotificationcenter, addobserver

use this code

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textChanged:) name:NSTextDidChangeNotification object:self.text3];
```

I can not get the notification I wanted.

But if I change the name or object to nil, it works. I wonder whether these two arguments can not be set non-nil simultaneously？

Comment: You can have a try, I think you will get noticed of all the notifications posted by `NSNotificationCenter`. If you want more details about the name or object see the [NSNotificationCenter reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html)

Comment: I know the reason finally.
My `text3` is a `NSTextField` object. And the actually object which fire the `NStextDidChangeNotification` is the associated `NSTextView` object.